# add svg image on blogger as header

Tags: image, header, svg, blogger

I am a complete rookie. I designed an svg image on illustrator. How do I put it on blogger as a header? I see online tutorials about codes, but I don't know where to paste the code on the html editor, or how to make my svg file into a code-to then paste it on the html editor.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the code for an svg image just open it with any text editor and copy everything inside.